# Using assembly reference natively

Tags: c++, .net, c

Can I make use of assembly reference of .NET environment natively? For example can I use `System.dll` reference by native C or C++ without existing of .NET Framework? I don't mean C++/CLI.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @svick: for learning purposes.

Comment: You can't do that without the .NET framework, you wouldn't have System.dll in the first place.  And you must load the CLR, the only way to execute managed code.  Which is possible, but entirely unpractical if you just want to use some of the managed classes in your C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/0a0342e4-caec-42d0-bfe5-e0930883f141. Easiest is probably to host the CLR if you want to call system.dll.